# OpenCV: what makes a device recognisable by OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I would like to know how OpenCV does to find devices that it can read from?
Can OpenCV only read from usb devices?

I have a video acquisition card (BlackMagic Intensity) and I until now used the blackMagic's SDK to retrieve the stream coming from the input port on the card, and converted it to a cv::Mat that I then use in my code. 
But can't I not develop some kind of C++ plugin for OpenCV so that I can use VideoCapture to access my blackMagic stream? wouldn't it be a cleaner way of doing this?

Hope you can help

Comment: AIUI OpenCV's video capture discovery varies by platform. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Im running on Arch linux, but my application has to be multiplatform (at least Windows...)